# Getting information of Process Close Reason

Tags: c#, process, exit-code, kill-process, windows-process

Suppose I have an Application.exe running on Windows. I want to log "My process was killed.", if someone else kills my process using task manager etc. How can I get the process closure information? Search results did not return any useful information. I am interested in C# and Windows solutions.

System.Diagnostics.Process class has an [ExitCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_ExitCode) property. But if process is already killed, how can i even use it?

Comment: Considering that if the process is killed, no more code is executed in it, you would have to place handling of that particular code outside of the process.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a "watchdog" process that keeps watch on `Application.exe` and logs the data-points you care about when the process terminates (whatever the reason may be)

Comment: you both are right, after a process is killed, there is nothing to do. thanks.